# Catching client connection disconnect in redis subscription

Tags: ruby, redis, sinatra

I'm trying to build a notifications system with Redis and Sinatra streams. However I can't seem to catch when connection closes down, so the blocking Redis subscription block seems to never close down. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
get '/user/:id/next_notification' do
stream :keep_open do |out|

    $redis.subscribe("notifications:#{params[:id]}") { |on|

        on.message { |channel, msg|
            $redis.unsubscribe
            out << msg
        }
    }

    out.callback { 
        puts "unsub"
        # $redis.unsubscribe 
    }

    out.errback { 
        puts "unsub"
        # $redis.unsubscribe
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Try setting a timeout when creating the redis object: `Redis.new(:timeout => 0)`

Comment: I tried Redis.new(host: <host>, port: <port>, timeout: 10) without sinatra stream but it never quits.

Answer (score 0):

Redis Subscription is a blocking call. So you need to execute it in a separate thread. Dunno how to do it in Ruby. But i'm sure there must be threading library in ruby.

Wrap the Blocking call in a try..catch and you will know when the connection has closed from the server side.